# Qt code comprehension

Tags: qt

i'm struggling with a code snippet for days now, i was wondering if someone could help me understand this code snippet. i'm not asking for code whatsoever, just someone to explain to me this please : (a uri appear to be the complete url to a service)

```
    void RestClient::_prepareRequest( QNetworkRequest& a_request, const QString& a_uri ){ 
        QSslConfiguration config(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
        config.setProtocol(QSsl::SslV3);
        config.setSslOption(QSsl::SslOptionDisableServerNameIndication, true);
        a_request.setSslConfiguration(config);
        a_request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        a_request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        QByteArray l_api_key; l_api_key.append( toQString( m_api_key) );
        QByteArray l_request_hash; 
    l_request_hash.append( toQString( _buildRequestHash( toStlString(a_uri) ) ) );
        a_request.setRawHeader("EMApikey", l_api_key );
        a_request.setRawHeader("EMRequestHash", l_request_hash );


        a_request.setUrl( QUrl( a_uri ) );
    }
```

Comment: a_uri seems to be the URL. The rest assembles a http(s) request. With which bits do you struggle particularly?

Comment: Thank you for answering Mr Osterfeld. I'm struggling with the setRawHeader methods what are they for ? i couldn't find a answer. Also why the Http request is that long. i saw some requests that are way shorter than this one. Thank you in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you've got there is a function taking two parameters, a reference to a `QNetworkRequest` and a constant reference to a `QString` for the URI you wish to access. The next lines sets `QSslConfiguration` to get the default SSL configuration for Qt's network access, and stores it in config. It then sets some further `QSsl` options and then sets the `a_request`'s SSL settings to be provided by the `config` you've just set.

Next up it sets some HTTP headers for the request, so these are reasonably standardised, so the `Accept` references what kind of information is acceptable for the response from the server which in this case is `xml` ([Accept header documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)). The `Content-type` tells the receiving server what sort of data you're sending in the request body.

The final stage sets a non-standard HTTP header, which is for the application API access key, after that it sets the URL you originally passed and the function is complete. After that the `QNetworkRequest` can be used with `QNetworkAccessManager` to send a request to a server, with an API key encoded in, and you'll receive an XML response in return.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, great explanation ! thank you very much !

Comment: If it is not curious from me, can i ask you if you code in objective-c for ios ?

Comment: Yeah, I do a bit of Objective-C as well.